# Doesn't Android Tint support API level 19?

Tags: android, button, colors, tint

Layout code for

Button:

```
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  style="@style/OneButton"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_setting"
  android:text="Setting"/>
```

Bitmap for drawable:

ic_setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_redeem"
        android:tint="@color/red"/>
```

This works fine in API level 21 and above.

Answer (score 2):

**[Tint Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html)**

> With Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above, you can tint bitmaps and
>   nine-patches defined as alpha masks. You can tint them with color
>   resources or theme attributes that resolve to color resources .

Comment: Can we achieve this in below API Level 21

Comment: @Sujay I did't try this yet . You should use `21` .

Comment: @Sujay I'm pretty sure that the support library does its job.

Comment: Yes yes sir @BobMalooga

Answer (score 1):

The AppCompat support library provides APIs that you can use to support pre-Lollipop devices (mainly `DrawableCompat#wrap()` and `DrawableCompat#setTintList()`). Check out [Chris Banes' blog post](http://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) for more information.